# "I understand where you're coming from" What does it imply

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-meaning

> "Thanks so much for getting back to me with your feedback regarding implementing a disclaimer to clearly outline our textbook solutions limits. I definitely understand where you are coming from, and I will gladly pass your feedback over to the XXXXXX Study team so we can work on making your experience as user-friendly as possible in the future. "

Here in this sentence does "I understand where you're coming from" means an agreement or disagreement ?

Comment: It implies that person knows your native place, your color, behavior, race, caste, religion etc. and he believes that your opinions are such because of them only. It is one of the most racist comment. It may also mean that person has already been to those place where you came from, so he knows your frustrations. It is one of the most racist phrase, I have ever encountered,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This means that the speaker understands the listener's point of view. While it's not a flat-out statement of unconditional agreement, it does mean that the speaker thinks the listener raised some good points and has explained their position. Usually it implies a level of agreement, but it could be possible for someone to "see where you're coming from" and still disagree with you.

In this case, the speaker thinks your feedback makes sense, and will pass it on to whoever might be able to act upon it. The speaker may not have the right information to properly agree or disagree with your claim, but it makes enough sense to pass on to someone who will.

Comment: I wanted to know whether it was meant as sarcastically in a mocking way ?.I had subscribed to a website for study solutions it claimed 2.5 million unlimited solutions I did some overtime on few semesters and mulitiple subjects .Which resulted in my account being blocked claiming .I have exceed usage limit.of more than 200 answers per week .

Comment: No, the response isn't sarcastic at all. It sounds pretty typical of a customer service response. The agent wants to make you feel that your concern has been received, understood, and will be acted upon. The customer service agent probably can't add the disclaimer or unlock your account or do anything else particularly useful himself, but he understands why you're unhappy and will raise the issue with the people who CAN do something.

Comment: Okay thanks @Matt .English is not my native language .So I am not much familiar with it nuances.Upvoted it and accepted it answer

Comment: When a politician says "I understand where you're coming from", it usually means, "I don't plan to vote the way you want me to on this issue, but I hope for your support anyway."  If the politician agreed with "you" about your request, the politician would instead say something about how the politician is working or fighting to achieve your request.

Answer (score -1):

"I understand where you are coming from". A technique used in the sales industry. Approaching the person, comment, subject with caution and logic. A calm, open, understanding, compassionate, mature approach is the most appropriate, professional tactic to deal with the other persons opinion, without offending them or implying that their opinion is wrong.